# does Lambda expression work on one interface?

Tags: java, java-8

Java 7

```
List<Person> personList = Person.createShortList();

// Sort with Inner Class
Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator<Person>() {
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getSurName().compareTo(p2.getSurName());
    }
});
```

Java 8

```
Collections.sort(personList, (Person p1, Person p2) -> 
                 p1.getSurName().compareTo(p2.getSurName()));

for (Person p : personList) {
    p.printName();
}
```

If the interface `Comparator` has 2 methods and not just one `compare` is it possible to use Lambda ?

for example

```
public interface Comparator<T> {
    int compare(T o1, T o2);
    int compareTest(T o1, T o2);
}
```

Comment: A lambda must implement an interface with exactly one abstract method. It can have any number of default methods.

Comment: By the way, you can use `Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getSurName()));` to avoid repeating yourself. Alternatively:  `Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.comparing(Person::getSurName));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas can be used where implementations of *functional interfaces* are expected. The definition of a functional interface is in [JLS§9.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.8):

> A *functional interface* is an interface that has just one abstract method (aside from the methods of `Object`), and thus represents a single function contract. This "single" method may take the form of multiple abstract methods with override-equivalent signatures inherited from superinterfaces; in this case, the inherited methods logically represent a single method.

So in your example, no, if there were two abstract methods on `Comparator` (`compare` and `compareTest`), you couldn't implement it using a lambda.

For example, this works:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Foo {
    void method1(int x);
}

public class Example {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().testFoo(x -> {
            System.out.println(x);
        });
    }

    private void testFoo(Foo f) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; ++x) {
            f.method1(x);
        }
    }
}
```

...but if we add to `Foo`:

```
// WON'T COMPILE
@FunctionalInterface
interface Foo {
    void method1(int x);
    void method2(int x);
}
```

...it won't compile anymore because it's no longer a functional interface. (If we removed the annotation, the interface would compile [of course], but our use of it via a lambda wouldn't.)

Note that we *could* add a *default* method to `Foo`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Foo {
    void method1(int x);
    default void method2(int x) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That's okay because there's only one *abstract* method on the interface.

Comment: To be precise, a functional interface must have exactly one `abstract` method that doesn’t match a method declared in `java.lang.Object`. This is especially important as the interface of the question, [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Comparator.html), has two `abstract` methods, but [one of them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) matches a [method declared in `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: So `Comparator` is a fine example of a functional interface having them all: `static` methods, `default` methods, and a second `abstract` method matching a method in `java.lang.Object`…

Answer (score 5):

Functional interfaces need exactly one abstract method which is not the case for your interface. However you could provide a default implementation for one of the methods. In that case it would work:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Comparator<T> {

    int compare(T o1, T o2);

    default int reverseCompare(T o1, T o2) {
        return compare(o2, o1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Heh, just came back from testing default methods (I wasn't sure they'd work) and updating my answer, and I find you've also called them out. :-)